# Functions & callback functions in javaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello…I couldn’t understand how those lines of javascript runs, any explanations?

```
// function declaration that takes in two arguments: a function for displaying
// a message, along with a name of a movie
function movies(messageFunction, name) {
  messageFunction(name);
}

// call the movies function, pass in the function and name of movie
movies(function displayFavorite(movieName) {
  console.log("My favorite movie is " + movieName);
}, "Finding Nemo");
```

Comment: Passing a function and a string to a function that executes it with the passed string. Try running it. Add some console.log to it

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling the movies method passing a function (displayFavorite) and a string ("Finding Nemo").

```
movies(function displayFavorite(movieName) {
   console.log("My favorite movie is " + movieName);
}, "Finding Nemo");
```

And here the movies function execute the function passed with the paramter name.

```
function movies(messageFunction, name) {
   messageFunction(name);
}
```

So, when you pass the displayFavorite function it execute with the movieName("Finding Nemo"). hence, the console will log "My favorite movie is Finding Nemo"

Comment: This looks like you are just repeating the two functions